# INDEX/MATCH to find value less than or equal to in range in Excel

Tags: excel

Hi I've tried searching under INDEX/MATCH and can't find the solution I'm looking for.

I'm trying to match E1 to the range A1:A12. The match has to be equal or less than E1.The result will pull from B1:B12.

For example, E1=137.87 needs to match with A3. The result would be B3.

I've tried this:

`=IF(E1<MIN(A1:A12),MIN(A1:A12),INDEX(B1:B12,MATCH(E1,A1:A12,-1)+1))`

But I can't account for when E2 equals a value in A1:A12.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you sort column A ascending (instead of descending)?

Comment: Yes I can change the sort on column A

Comment: Sort was the fix thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `VLOOKUP()`. First, sort on Column A, Ascending (going from smallest value to highest).

Then use this in `E2`: `=VLOOKUP(E1,A1:B5,2,TRUE)`

Adjust the range as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Failure to find an exact match will give an error, so try an exact match first, but wrap it in [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) so if it fails to find an exact match it defaults to an inexact match. However ensure your list is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort your data on ascending order of Column-A (your key column),
then =INDEX($A$1:$B$12,MATCH($E$1,$A$1:$A$12,1),2) should hopefully solve your problem.

Note :  This would work only if the data is sorted on ascending order of key-column.